# Is there any way to use colorPicker in Angular WYSIWYG directive without using jQuery

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, wysiwyg, contenteditable

When I remove the jquery refrence color picker is not working in WYSIWYG directive and in my project I should not use `jQuery` so is there any way to do this without using jquery? Or is there any other editor which has no jquery refrence?[plunker with jquery ref](https://plnkr.co/edit/BRCoWcmAl9UhHXD6vdIq?p=preview)

Comment: How is it "not working"? Your plunker seems to behave the same if you either have or don't have a jQuery reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**demo** : http://so.lucafilosofi.com/is-there-any-way-to-use-colorpicker-in-angular-wysiwyg-directive-without-using-j/

The problem you have actually is not with `colorPicker` but with the `wysiwyg` module itself as stated in it's code comments:

> Requires: Twitter-bootstrap, fontawesome, jquery, angularjs, bootstrap-color-picker

anyway, fortunately that module is using jquery only for bootstrap and tooltip plugin...

so i have:

- replaced the original bootstrap with [UI Bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) for angularjs
- added [ngSanitize](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize) module that provides functionality to sanitize HTML.
- hacked the `wysiwyg` module to use the `uib-tooltip` directive
- created a new ad-hoc directive for the `contenteditable` div
- **source** [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/27AzZkzMn1qnexrzT6Dl)

hope this help. ;-)

Comment: Thanks @Luca but if i try to `$watch` the `scope.data.text` watch is not working for it

Comment: @Syed Rasheed: check the updated https://plnkr.co/edit/2BIN4HKDzvjPxxniNuCb i have also fixed another minor bug

Comment: Thanks But again if i keep `value` in watch for saving the text entered in that editor it is not retrieving it!

Comment: @Syed Rasheed: Hi, i made a major rewrite of the module look into the source for changes, it should work now! ;) https://plnkr.co/edit/27AzZkzMn1qnexrzT6Dl?p=preview